# Remove selected item from BindingContext

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, forms

Given the following code:

```
 DialogResult result3 = MessageBox.Show("Proceed With Checkout?", "Request Granted",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

                if (result3 == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    int delete = int.Parse("s_NTextBox.Text");
                    this.BindingContext[iTEMDataSet, "ITEM"].RemoveAt(0);
                }
                if (result3 == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    //quantity = quantity - 1;
                    //quantityTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(quantity);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
```

At the line `this.BindingContext[iTEMDataSet, "ITEM"].RemoveAt(0)` I would like to remove the currently selected item. The current code always removes the first item. How to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Where is your question? What are you using for DB access in the first place?

Comment: The question is WAY too large. You should divide to conquer.

Comment: What's this have to do with database? (removed tag)  Datasets yes, databases no

Answer (score 1):

Use `Position` property.

```
this.BindingContext[iTEMDataSet, "ITEM"].
    RemoveAt(this.BindingContext[iTEMDataSet, "ITEM"].Position);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand you're going to delete a record from database which is matched to your given ID in the textbox.

So, just write below code if DialogResult.Yes is true

```
        int numberOfRowsAffected = 0;
        bool isDeleted = false;
        string query = @"DELETE FROM targetTable WHERE ID=@ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", deletedItemID));
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cn.Open();
                object result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                isDeleted = Convert.ToInt32(result) > 0 ? true : false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isDeleted = false;
        }
```